# How to find index of first and last column and first and last row which does not contain only zeros or only ones inside?

Tags: c++

I have matrix of `0` and `1` packed inside `vector<int>` filled by rows (first row, second row and so on..). How to find index of first and last column and first and last row which does not contain only zeros or only ones inside ?
I have iterated four times with loop and compare but is there faster and more elegant way to do this ?

```
for example result here is columns with indexes 1 and 4 and rows with 1 and 4.
0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 1 0 0
0 1 0 0 1
0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 1 0
```

Comment: So in your example is that a `vector<int>` containing `25` `int`s? In [row-major order](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-major_order)?

Comment: `std::find_if` with normal and reverse iterators should do the job quite easily.

Answer (score 0):

I would say, you just need two iterations: One iteration for rows and one iteration for columns.

If I understand the question right, this coding should show how it could be coded (just a draft):

```
int firstRow = -1;
int lastRow = -1;
for (row=0; row<numRows; row++) {
   int cnt = 0;
   for (col=0; col<numCols; col++) {
      cnt += vec[row][col];
   }
   if (cnt != 0 && cnt != numCols) {
      if (firstRow == -1) firstRow = row;
      lastRow = row;
   }
}
// output firstRow, lastRow
```

Do the same for columns.

This coding is not necessarily faster than four iterations. When four iterations are made from the start and the end, they are faster if the columns are nearer to the limits. But it saves you a little coding.